# WooCommerce Social Login Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used social login plugin for woocommerce myaccount page, but the plugin providing social login to my wp-admin.this not correct way. How to fix redirect to my account.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided any references to the plugin you're using, as also a code sample of what you're trying to achieve. In case you're talking about the WooCommerce Social Login plugin (https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-social-login/), it'd be as easy as placing this shortcode anywhere on your pages or widget `[woocommerce_social_login_buttons return_url='https://mystore.com/my-account']`. The return_url attribute is the page to which customers will be redirected after signing in.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using [WooCommerce Social Login](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-social-login/) shortcode on your pages and posts, doing as follows should allow you to redirect your customers to any page.

e.g: For logged out users, this will ask them to sign in. For logged-in users, they can link accounts to their site account.

`[woocommerce_social_login_buttons return_url="https://mystore.com/my-account"]`

Simple change the link for the **return_url** attribute. The return_url attribute is the page to which customers will be redirected after signing in successfully.

If you're editing your theme's .php templates for putting the buttons in place, use the available function instead:

```
<?php
// If user is logged in, allows sign in, else, allows social account linking 

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    // Outputs "link account" buttons only to logged-in users

    woocommerce_social_login_link_account_buttons( $return_url = null );

} else {

    // Outputs "create account" buttons only to non-logged-in users

    woocommerce_social_login_buttons( $return_url = null );

}
?>
```

Again, edit `$return_url` variable accordingly in order to redirect the user to any page after signing in or linking accounts successfully.

e.g `$return_url = 'members-area'`, where "members-area" is the permalink of the page you're redirecting users to.